# Form loaded with jQuery doesn't update table row sent through AJAX/PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

*I will simplify my question as much as I possibly can and only include what's relevant.*

#### What I am trying to achieve & how it works

I got a **HTML** table loaded with all the rows from my database, each row will have the **ID** from the database and an update button which opens up a modal - works great.

Inside the modal that opens, there's a form loaded with jQuery's `.load()` from a **HTML** document named `update.html`. I insert the form fields with the values that is already in the database for the current row selected. I do this by creating an array called `columns`.

This all works perfect, however upon submitting the form to **AJAX** which sends it to **PHP** - it will not update the row with the given values in the input fields.

#### Code w/ filenames, what it contains and does:

**index.php** - **HTML/PHP** Table DOM:

```
// popup modal
<div class="popup-overlay">
    <div class="popup-content">
        // content getting loaded by jquery when updateModal() has been fired.
    </div>
</div>

// loop each row and get the **ID** 
<?php
    foreach($result as $rows) {
    $rowId = $rows['id'];
?>

// display rows and set the ID
<tr id="<?php echo $rowId;?>">
    <td><?php echo $rows['ip']; ?></td>
    //row for update button, opens the modal and fires updateModal() function
    <td><a onclick="updateModal(this.closest('tr').id)">Update</a></td>
</tr>
```

**update.html** - Loaded **HTML** form:

```
<h1>Update row - Modal</h1>
<form id="update-form" name="form">
    label for="ip"><h3>IP address</h3></label>
    <input class="form-input-style" type="text" name="ip" id="ip" value="">

    <input type="hidden" name="update" id="update" value="1"/>
    <button class="button-style button-green" type="submit" name="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

**popup.js** - Toggle modal, load the HTML form, Insert table row values in the form fields, AJAX request to PHP with serialized form data

Toggle the modal and get the ID (works):

```
// create columns array
var columns = [];
function toggleModal(id) {
    columns.splice(0, columns.length);
    // find the row id that's echoed by PHP in index.php
    $('#'+ id).find('td').each(function(){
        columns.push($(this).text());
    });

    $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content, #popup-close, .popup-background").addClass("active");
    $("#popup-close, .popup-background").on("click", function(){
        $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content, #popup-close, .popup-background").removeClass("active");
    });
};
```

Insert values, fire `toggleModal()`, load **HTML** modal and send the loaded form data on form submission:

```
function updateModal(id) {  
    toggleModal(id);
    
    // assoc array with all the form fields, simplified to only contain IP row
    function insertValues() {
        const inputValues = {
            ip              :   columns[0]
        };

        // get key and set current row value that's in the database which I want to update, works.
        for(inputName in inputValues) {
            document.getElementById(inputName).value = inputValues[inputName];
        };
    };
    
    // load the modal HTML from update.html 
    // and create and prepend a hidden input field to pass the rowId (probably a better solution for this.)
    $('.popup-content').load('/right/path/here/update.html', function() {
        insertValues(columns);
        $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            value: id,
            name: 'rowId'
        }).prependTo('#update-form');
    });

    //AJAX request that fires on submission
    $('#update-form').on('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var inputData = $('#update-form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: inputData,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**update.php** - Get the form data and update in the **SQL** database
(error handling removed to simplify, they didnt return anything anyways)

```
//removed connection file and usersession file to minify question
if(isset($_POST['update']==1)) {

    $id = $_POST['rowId'];
    $ip = $_POST['ip'];
                    
    $sql = "UPDATE `totaloversiktliste2` SET `ip`=:ip WHERE `id`=:id";
    $args = array(
        ':ip'           =>  $ip,
        ':id'           =>  $id
    );

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmt->execute($args);
}
```

#### My question and some comments

**Question**

What am I doing wrong here? I don't expect to be spoonfed, but led in the right direction. Any debugging tips, general suggestions or comments are much welcomed and appreciated.

**What happens**

There are no errors in the console, it only refreshes my page and does nothing. The `Network` console show that the form data has been sent through the HTTP request and gives Status `200 OK`. No logs are to be found.

**Comments**

I started off by trying to find this out myself several days ago and struggled with the same issue since. It seems like something is not getting properly received even though after my logical thinking - it should.

I've tweaked my code so much I'm not even sure what I've done wrong anymore - rewritten it so many times and tried several different methods. What I think is wrong the values are not properly getting set/sent or the order the functions are being fired, and since AJAX is asynchronous, that may have something to do with it and how I load the HTML form - but I can't tell anymore.

I hope this wasn't too long, but I wanted to explain as best as I could with great detail, yet simplified. *Grateful for every answer or comment that gives me more knowledge on how to tackle this.*

Comment: `$('#update-form').on('submit'` – that will select the element with that ID, that is _currently_ in the DOM at this moment, and add a submit handler to it. But with your `$('.popup-content').load()` call, you are replacing that element with a different one. That one does not have any submit handler bound to it. The easiest solution to your problem is called _event delegation_.

Comment: @04FS Many, many thanks. This seems to be the exact cause I was unable to find. I will look into event delegation when I’m in front of a computer and I’ll most likely be able to fix the issue accordingly.

Comment: @04FS I've added an answer to my question, thanks again for leading me in the right direction and telling me about *event delegation*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The solution:

As mentioned by [@04FS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10955263/04fs) the solution was simply using [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#introduction).
A good recommended read. Learned a ton.

I first moved my AJAX call into the `.load()` function and then instead of calling the ID of the form itself (which would not exist yet), I would call `$(this)` on form submission using `.on()`.

**Code example - popup.js**

```
$('.popup-content').load('/right/path/here/update.html', function() {
    insertValues(columns);
    $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        value: id,
        name: 'rowId'
    }).prependTo('#update-form');

    $(this).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        var inputData = $('#update-form').serialize();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: inputData,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```